# SharePoint: Customize Search Results Refinement Panel

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I know there are threads out there about making changes to the refinement panel and they have so far been very helpful but now I have a question that I need a bit more assistance with.

In the search results, would there be a way to add a filter to the refinement planel that would filter based on a tag I have used in a column in the libray?

For example, let's say I have three committees that meet every week and I have minutes for all of them. In my search results, I may want to look up a keyword discussed, but only interested in a certain committee. This would have already been identified in a column in the library.

How do i do this? I believe it has something to do with mapped properties but I need some steps from someone willing to help! TY :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add a new mapped property in your search service application and map it to the crawled property that contains the field you want to filter by.

You can then refer to this mapped property when you edit you refinement panel on your search results page.

To do this, edit your search results page and then edit the refinement panel web part. Under Refinement section you need to edit the Filter Category Definition XML and then save your page.

Comment: Hi Lee. Thanks! I can do the second part, but I am not sure if IT has given me the permissions needed to add the mapped propery to the search service application. How do i check that?

Comment: If you have permissions to the search service application you will be able to navigate to Application Management -> Manage Services and open the Search Service Administration page.